# Less writing for type conversion possible?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Let's assume you loaded a dynamic library using `dlopen()` or `LoadLibrary()` on Windows, and you want to get a symbol from it and cast it to a specific function type. It is so unbelievable redundant to write the type twice!

```
void (*Test)(int, float) =
        reinterpret_cast<void (*Test)(int, float)>(dlsym(handle, "Test"));
```

I want the code to be compilable without the C++11 standard, therefore the `auto` keyword is not an option. I tried using templates because compilers can often detect the template parameters from the given parameters, but it does not seem to work for the type of the assignment value.

```
template <typename T>
T GetSym(void* handle, const char* symbol) {
    return (T) dlsym(handle, symbol);
}

void (*Test)(int, float) = GetSym(handle); // does not compile
```

Is there a way to bring less redundancy into the code? When retrieving a huge number of functions from a dynamically loaded library, it is awful to write each and every cast twice!

Comment: Why do you think `auto` was added?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  Does it have something like `gcc`'s `typeof` extension?

Comment: @brianbeuning Won't help much, there can be so many different function signatures, and typedef'ing each variation.. ouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an evil templated conversion operator.

```
struct proxy {
public:
    proxy(void* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<T>(ptr);
    }
private:
    void* ptr;
};

proxy GetSym(void* handle, const char* symbol) {
    return proxy(dlsym(handle, symbol));
}
```

Comment: That's not even a legal cast anyway, since function pointers and object pointers aren't guaranteed to have any layout or size in common. The best I can think of is to memcpy the void pointer you get from `dlsym` into the function pointer.

Comment: @Kerrek It's fine in the platforms where `dlsym` exists.

Comment: FWIW, the POSIX specification itself recommends using `void(*TestFN)(int, float); *(void **) (&fptr) = dlsym(handle, sym);` instead, but I find that quite laughable, to be honest. The reinterpret_cast is *conditionally-supported with implementation-defined results* (and relevant implementations support it with the expected results). The hack suggested by the POSIX spec accesses an lvalue through a reference to the wrong type (i.e. violates the strict aliasing rules)